# 'Publishing to Tomcatv8.0 Server at localhost' failed with multiple errors

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, macos, maven

I am JSP Servlet newbie and facing the following error with my JSP Servlet project on Tomcat server v8.0

> Publishing failed with multiple errors
> Error reading file /Users/{{user name}}/Documents/Data/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/C::/home/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar

> /Users/{{user name}}/Documents/Data/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/C::/home/maven.repo/org/springframework/spring-core/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar (No such file or directory)

I am using Eclipse Juno on Mac and changed the `settings.xml` of maven to match my local maven repository but still facing the same error. What am I missing here?.

**EDIT:** Thought this will add some information -
I do see that the `::` in the path is odd since when I copy the path form the folder details form finder and paste it in editor I see:

> /Users/{{user name}}/Documents/Data/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/C:/home/maven.repo/

That is where the curiosity is - I have set the above shown path in my settings.xml and yet when I start Tomcat, it searches for the path with `::` which means that there is another place from where it is trying to get the path while starting up. And I do not know what is that place - That is where I need help.

Comment: Anything about those paths look suspiciously bad to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I experimented with the `<localRepository>` element in my maven `settings.xml` file which looked something like this:

> /Users/{{user name}}/Documents/Data/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/C/home/maven.repo

I just commented it out and then did a maven update on the project. It then created and used the default maven repo and the errors resolved.

I came to this conclusion by first manually creating a directory `C//` - trying to follow the `::` since I was sure that  `C/` was read as `C:` but when I made that change the errors now posted `::::` - so technically the path was not read properly either by Eclipse or by OSX. But now is finally resolved.

Comment: i've had the same problem and you solution give a hint to resolve it, i had `<localRepository>C:\Users\yous\.m2</localRepository>` which is pointing to the default local respository and after deleting this line  it works, maven used the same defaut path as it mentioned in the comment `Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository`, I don't know why this weird behaviour happened (of course I did also a lot of `clean instal` and `maven => update`)